# Windows Update starting itself through its disabled

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've recently reinstalled Windows 10 Home because of some system errors and during config I modified registry to disable Windows Update and Update Orchestrator Service because they always are taking a huge part of my internet bandwidth.

The problem is that through both are set to disable they are auto starting at boot of system and randomly during using a PC (mostly during playing online)

**What I've done**

Modified registry keys for both services, took ownership and removed full control for SYSTEM to not reset it (through services are running in services and registry they are still disabled)

Used registry method provided [here](https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/disable-windows-10-update-registry-8523.html)

I tried to modify Task Scheduler to remove triggers for both but I was able to only remove the WU one. When I was trying to remove UOS I was getting error that this account got no rights (through it's the only account on PC)

In services in recovery tab when I'm trying to set action after failure I'm getting prompt 'Access denied'

Can anyone tell me how to prevent it from start till I want to turn it on? (I would rather not reinstall system because I've already downloaded some huge files)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WaaSMedicSvc. That is a service specifically in place to get Windows Update back up and running, users be darned. You'll have to do the whole thing with removing full control for that service as well - and you'll have to do it over the registry, because the normal interface will refuse to do it.
What can also work is renaming the Windows Update DLL - although I have seen Windows 10 recreate the Windows Update DLL out of thin air, so there's no guarantee either.